# Show $E[AB]=E[A]E[B]$ for A,B independent, not necessarily finite with a continuous density function.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm taking a course in proability and we always use $E[AB]=E[A]E[B]$ without explaining.
I'm a bit rusty with lebesgue integral and I think this problem will help me to get better at it.

> Problem: Let A,B be independtent r.v. Prove E[AB]=E[A]E[B].

I only wrote $$E[AB]=\int _\Omega X dP=^*\int _\Omega x\ d\mu _{AB}(x)$$

where  $\mu_{AB}$ is the push forward messure for X, meaning $\mu _{AB} (X)=P(AB\in X)$

I'm not sure why the second equallity is correct and how do I continue.

how do i split $\mu_{AB} (X)=P(AB\in X) =...=\mu_A \mu_B$

Comment: Approximate A and B by elementary functions and then take limits. For an alternative approach, $E(AB)=E(E(AB|A))=E(AE(B))=E(A)E(B)$ (I don't recall if this is circular, hopefully it isn't)

Comment: There's nothing to prove really. If $A$ has distribution $\mu$ (i.e. A pushes forward the probability measure to get $\mu$ on $\Bbb{R}$) and $B$ has distribuition $\nu$. Then the definition of independence of $A$ and $B$ is that the joint distribution which $(A,B)$ induces on $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ (by pushing forward) is equal to the product measure $\mu\times\nu$. In this case, by Fubini's theorem, you have that $\displaystyle E(AB)=\int_{\Bbb{R}^{2}}ab\,d\mu_{(A,B)}(a,b)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}ab\,d\mu(a)\,d\nu(b)=(\int_{\Bbb{R}}a\,d\mu(a))(\int_{\Bbb{R}}b\,d\nu(b))=E(A)E(B)$

Answer (score 1):

The key part, of course, is the assumption that the events are independent, and for the integration part, it is the Fubini's theorem. Consider the sequence of random variables $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$. Then, if $(f_k)$ are independent (denoted as $f_{i} \perp f_{j}$), then $\mu_{f_1, \ldots, f_n} = \Pi_{k=1}^{n}\mu_{f_k}$. To see this, proceed as follows: \begin{align*}\mu_{f_1, \ldots, f_n}(\Pi_{k=1}^{n}A_k)&= \mu(\cap_{k=1}^{n}f^{-1}_{k}(A_k))\\& \underset{\perp}{=} \Pi_{k=1}^{n}\mu(f_{k}^{-1}(A_k))\\& = \Pi_{k=1}^{n}\mu_{f_k}(A_k)\\&= \Pi_{k=1}^{n}\mu_{f_k}\end{align*} Let's call this result $(*)$. Then, in particular, $\mu_{AB}=\mu_{A}\times \mu_{B}$, when $A \perp B$.

In general, if $f_{i} \perp f_{j}$, then you have the desired result \begin{align*}E(\Pi_{k=1}^{n}f_{k})&=\int_{X}\Pi_{k=1}^{n}f_{k}d\mu\\&=\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}\Pi_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}d_{u_{f_1,\ldots,f_n}}\\&\underset{(*)}{=}\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}\Pi_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}d(\Pi_{k=1}^{n}\mu_{f_k})\\&\underset{(**)}{=}\Pi_{k=1}^{n}\int_{{\bf R}}x_{k}d\mu_{f_k}\\&=\Pi_{k=1}^{n}E(f_k)\end{align*} where $(**)$ is justified by the Fubini's theorem.

In fact, if $A$ and $B$ are such that $f(a,b)$ is their joint distribution and $f_{1}(a)$ and $f_{2}(b)$ are their marginals of $A$ and $B$, respectively, and assuming that $A \perp B$, and if $g(A)$ and $h(B)$ are such that $E(g(A))$ and $E(g(B))$ exist, we can write \begin{align*}E(g(A)h(B))&=\int_{{\bf R}^2}g(a)h(b)f(a,b)dbda\\&\underset{\perp}{=}\int_{{\bf R}^{2}}g(a)h(b)f_{1}(a)f_{2}(b)dbda\\&=E(g(A))E(h(B))\end{align*}
by Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $A,B$ are independent then $p_{A,B}(a,b)=p_A(a)p_B(b)$, where $p_X(x)$ is the density function of $X$ evaluated at $X=x$.

In general:

$$E[AB] = \int_A\int_B ab p_{A,B}(a,b) dadb$$

Using the fact that $p_{A,B}(a,b)=p_A(a)p_B(b)$ lets us rewrite the integral:

$$E[AB] = \left(\int_A ap_A(a)da\right)\left(\int_B b p_{B}(b)db\right) = E[A]E[B]$$